# I want fullcalendar validrange change when change datpicer date

Tags: fullcalendar

I want fullcalendar validrange change when change datpicer date.

i want when datepicker change fullcalendar validrange same change

```js
$("#travel_start_day2").on("change", function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    validRange: function inputDate() {
      return {
        start: $("#travel_start_day2").val(),
        end: $.fullCalendar.moment($("#travel_end_day2").val()).add(1, 'days')
      }
    }
  })
}); //datepicker


validRange: function inputDate() {
  return {
    start: $("#travel_start_day2").val(),
    end: $.fullCalendar.moment($("#travel_end_day2").val()).add(1, 'days')

  }
},
```

Comment: As per your last question, there is no need to add "please help me" to your posts. Also, please try to avoid txtspk here - "please" is not more effort to type than "plz". If your question looks like no effort has gone into it, you will be less likely to get help.

Comment: right now the code is re-initialising the calendar when the datepicker changes. You haven't actually said what is wrong, but is that your problem? You can set fullCalendar options after initialisation using the functions as documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/